# Lib error while executing python file with WSL (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL')

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First of all, sorry about my english, this isn't my native language.

```
    PS C:\Users\...... wsl ./Test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I made this **Test.py** using pycharm. Its a wordcloud program and it works fine with pycharm.
However, when I try to execute this file with ***wsl ./*** it shows me the error above. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment you are checking if Pillow is installed in Windows, but you are running your Windows-hosted `Test.py` in WSL, i.e. using python interpreter and libraries that are installed in WSL.
To illustrate, Powershell session in Windows, using python libpath from conda:

```
(base) PS C:\> python -c "import os; print(os.__file__)"
C:\Users\ml\Miniconda3\lib\os.py
```

Powershell session in Windows, but executing code in WSL, python and libpath from Ubuntu:

```
(base) PS C:\> wsl python3 -c "import os; print(os.__file__)"
/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py
```

You do need to check your Pillow installation, but in WSL.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to install like i am using linux os and it worked, no more PIL error.
But it looks like the wordcloud lib does'nt  work in linux (i probably may be wrong), so... a little further on i came across another library error :(

Comment: @BrunoRibeiro,  I'd recommend you to familiarize  yourself with virtual environments to minimize such reproducibility issues. PyCharm should have a good built-in support for venv, pipenv & conda.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not have Pillow installed, and the code wants it to run.
To install it you should just need to run

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

or you can follow the instructions on [the pillow website](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Hope that helps [:

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried your tip, yet still not working.
When I try to install, it only tells me that all requirements are already satisfied.
In cmd, when trying to uninstall Pillow, i got this message:

Found existing installation: Pillow 9.1.1
Uninstalling Pillow-9.1.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\....\site-packages\pil\*
    c:\users\.....\site-packages\pillow-9.1.1.dist-info\*
Proceed (Y/n)? 

In IDLE, i can run: from PIL import Image.
Am I missing something?